# c# Use of public static properties outside derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm a beginner in C#. I want to do the following:

Having class A in namespace nA I need to implement class B in namespace nB that inherits everything from A and adds some functionality, that's fine.

In ProjectA I have:

```
namespace nA{
    public abstract class A{
        public const int a = 1;
    }
}
```

in ProjectB t I have:

```
using ProjectA.nA;
namespace nB{
    class abstract B : A{
        public const int b = 2; 
    }
}
```

and in ProjectC I have

```
using ProjectB.nB;
namespace nC{
    class C{
        void someMethod(){
            int valueA = B.a //error, nB.B does not contain a definition for 'a'
            int valueB = B.b //works just fine
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This line should be: `int valueA = A.a`. Always reference static members by their class names, not a derived class name. This includes constants.

Comment: You may also need to include `using ProjectA.nA;` in Project C, but I'm not 100% sure on that. Did you try that?

Comment: It's a restriction that I can't include Project A in Project C. Sorry I didn't specify that.

Comment: That's an odd restriction. But you could add `public const int a = A.a;` to class B. What are you really trying to achieve? Seems like an arbitrary need and restriction lacking the context of real use.

Comment: @Maluchi No it isn't. If you are including ProjectB, you *are* including ProjectA already, because ProjectB uses ProjectA. If the restriction is that you can't import the namespace (`using ProjectA.nA`) (but why?), then just write `int valueA = ProjectA.nA.A.a;`.

Comment: What I need is to build some kind of "wrapper" so both (unrelated) projects A and C can use the implementation in A, the inherited version B is simply to add some properties and methods.

Comment: @Maluchi It doesn't make sense for `B` to "inherit" constants from `A` because `B` can never be treated as `A`, only *instances* of `B` can be treated as instances of `A`. There are no instance objects involved here, the class is simply acting as a namespace for the const. If you want all the consts listed together, why don't you put them in a  fourth class that all three of `A`, `B`, and `C` can access? `A` still wouldn't need to "know" about the consts that only `B` uses.

Comment: @nmclean That makes sense, I'm clearly facing a bad design. If anyone can tell me _why_ the constants aren't visible or point me in the right direction of how inheritance works I'd be forever grateful, every documentation/tutorial/article about inheritance in C# shows only basic inheritance and I don't understand why the avobe code isn't working!

Comment: @Maluchi It isn't visible because you're working with classes, not instances. Look at the [msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx) for inheritance. `WorkItem` defines a `currentID` attached to the class (static) as well as an `ID` property attached to each instance (non-static). Each instance needs its own `ID` whether it's `ChangeRequest` or plain `WorkItem`, so `ID` is inherited and also accessible from any `ChangeRequest` instance. But there's no need for the `currentID` managed by `WorkItem` to be accessed through `ChangeRequest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it should work, I would suggest that you check you're not missing any assembly references in your projects.

Comment: Thanks! What I wanted to know is if should (or shouldn't work). After adding the reference it worked just fine!

Answer (score 1):

Constants and static members are always accessed via the class that actually defines thems. `A.a` will work. Also note that it is accessible from any class, not just an inheritor.

Answer (score 0):

In project B write:

```
using ProjectA.nA;
namespace nB{
    class abstract B : A{
        public const int a = A.a; 
        public const int b = 2; 
    }
}
```

Then project C should compile. Or one could do:

```
using ProjectB.nB;
namespace nC{
    class C{
        void someMethod(){
            int valueA = ProjectA.nA.a;
            int valueB = B.b;
        }
    }
}
```

Since ProjectC will have to reference ProjectA.

The better lesson here is to think in terms of separation of concerns. If class C should not know directly about class A, then it should also not now about a constant class A defines. Instead, there should be some functionality in B which uses the constant and makes sense for what class B is attempting to accomplish. Hence, what class B is concerned with that uses class A and provides this appropriate separation.